# I get a keyerror when I try to get data from a json in python

Tags: python, json, api, dictionary

I have this json, from an api, i need to get the data, but I don't understand why some of them I get and others I get "keyerror".

```
{
    "images": [
        {
            "OS-EXT-IMG-SIZE:size": 13167616,
            "created": "2021-07-13T09:35:56Z",
            "id": "15f490a5-9b64-4315-a592-3933e91356a5",
            "links": [
                {
                    "href": "http://192.168.1.82:8774/v2.1/7d8fed2119e04ee79e15b5a2fac2f5da/images/15f490a5-9b64-4315-a592-3933e91356a5",
                    "rel": "self"
                },
                {
                    "href": "http://192.168.1.82:8774/7d8fed2119e04ee79e15b5a2fac2f5da/images/15f490a5-9b64-4315-a592-3933e91356a5",
                    "rel": "bookmark"
                },
                {
                    "href": "http://192.168.1.82:9292/images/15f490a5-9b64-4315-a592-3933e91356a5",
                    "rel": "alternate",
                    "type": "application/vnd.openstack.image"
                }
            ],
            "metadata": {},
            "minDisk": 0,
            "minRam": 0,
            "name": "cirrios",
            "progress": 100,
            "status": "ACTIVE",
            "updated": "2021-07-13T09:35:57Z"
        },
        {
            "OS-EXT-IMG-SIZE:size": 1020264448,
            "created": "2021-07-11T15:14:03Z",
            "id": "ba417b6f-edde-4862-8425-6d3b1d545dcc",
            "links": [
                {
                    "href": "http://192.168.1.82:8774/v2.1/7d8fed2119e04ee79e15b5a2fac2f5da/images/ba417b6f-edde-4862-8425-6d3b1d545dcc",
                    "rel": "self"
                },
                {
                    "href": "http://192.168.1.82:8774/7d8fed2119e04ee79e15b5a2fac2f5da/images/ba417b6f-edde-4862-8425-6d3b1d545dcc",
                    "rel": "bookmark"
                },
                {
                    "href": "http://192.168.1.82:9292/images/ba417b6f-edde-4862-8425-6d3b1d545dcc",
                    "rel": "alternate",
                    "type": "application/vnd.openstack.image"
                }
            ],
            "metadata": {},
            "minDisk": 0,
            "minRam": 0,
            "name": "centos",
            "progress": 100,
            "status": "ACTIVE",
            "updated": "2021-07-11T15:14:22Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

I search for the data I am interested in with a for, but with "progress", "minDisk", "minRam", "status" I get keyerror, but not with "name" or "id".

```
try:
    result = requests.get(req["images"], headers=headers)
    result_data = json.loads(result.content)
except Exception as e :
    print('0')
    sys.exit("\nError requesting %s, please check conectivity" %(req["images"],))

for dato in result_data["images"] :
    print(f'Name={dato["name"]}')
    print(f'Id={dato["id"]}')
    print(f'Progress={dato["progress"]}')
    print(f'minDisk={dato["minDisk"]}')
    print(f'minRam={dato["minRam"]}')
```

I've been stuck for a long time and I can't figure it out, what could I be doing wrong?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "openstack3.py", line 263, in <module>
    print(f'Progress={dato["progress"]}')
KeyError: 'progress'
```

this its full error traceback

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: What do you get when you add `print(list(dato.keys()))` before `print(f'Name={dato["name"]}')`?

Comment: obtengo : ['id', 'links', 'name']

Comment: Thanks for the update. So, what makes you think that these other keys: `"progress", "minDisk", "minRam", "status"` will ever be present in the data returned?

Comment: I thought that as they came out of the json they could be taken, so I couldn't show them at all?

Comment: Ok, let me ask this in another way: Your snippet of `json` shows these keys present, but you have also shown that sometimes they go missing. What does it mean to you if these keys are missing? Do you have default values for the missing ones? Would you want to ignore that image if there is vital information missing?

Comment: I understand, it is predefined information, so it is not interesting to take them, right?

I'm a bit new to this